# Mondrian - Parent with filtered children

Tags: filter, mdx, parent, mondrian

I want to create a topcount of users per product category. 
My product dimension is like the following [Product].[ProductCategory].[ProductType] Users of my application can filter the products and it return a set like this: [Product].[ProductCategory1].[ProductType1], [Product].[ProductCategory3].[ProductType5], ...

Now I got the topcount per product category, but it doesn't filter the children of the category: the types. Example of my query:

```
SELECT
  NON EMPTY {[Measures].[Orders]} ON COLUMNS, 
  NON EMPTY 
    {Order(
       Generate(
         Exists(
           [Product].[ProductCategory].Members
          ,{
            [Product].[ProductCategory1].[ProductType1]
           ,[Product].[ProductCategory3].[ProductType5]
           }
         )
      , TopCount(
         Crossjoin(
           {[Product].[ProductCategory].currentmember}
          ,{[USER].[UserName].Members}
         )
        ,5.0
        ,[Measures].[Orders]
       )
     )
   , [Measures].[Orders]
   , DESC
  )
  } ON ROWS 
FROM [Products]
```

The [Product].[ProductCategory].currentmember doesn't return the category with filtered product types.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: your Exists is not required as it will always return Category1 and Category3 but the script looks fine. Is the more compact `*` notation ok in Mondrian?

Comment: where is the filter in your script? you mention a filter but I cannot see one. Your script will return the top 5 users per category: what else do you want it to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem using a calculated measure to filter the measure with the product members.

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[FilteredOrders] AS
'SUM(exists([Product].[ProductCategory].currentmember.children, {[Product].[ProductCategory1].[ProductType1]
       ,[Product].[ProductCategory3].[ProductType5]}), [Measures].[Orders])'
```

Answer (score 0):

(Not an answer but a script to hopefully help find the answer)

I'm guessing your question is in connection with the Exists section of the script. Does this return a result you expect?

```
SELECT
  {[Measures].[Orders]} ON COLUMNS, 
  Exists(
     [Product].[ProductCategory].Members
    ,{
        [Product].[ProductCategory1].[ProductType1]
       ,[Product].[ProductCategory3].[ProductType5]
     }
  )
  ON ROWS 
FROM [Products]
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. Sorry for the confusion. I want a top 5 users per category, but I want to be able to filter the children [ProductType] under [ProductCategory] and return the categories for the top. The except is not working because it return the categories without the filtered children. Working with subqueries is not possible in mondrian, so I can't do that.